# VS Code memory view with GDB debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I try to access memory viewer on VSCode with GDB debugger as suggested by the debugger to debug C++ code. However typing `-exec info registers` as suggested by debug console gives no response.

I am using VSCode 1.37.1

Answer (score 0):

To examine the memory area you should use the `x` command

Here is the page to find help about using it : https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory.html

In your case you have to use `-exec x` for `x`